# How to get customer order numbers in one dropdown?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, drop-downs

how can i get customer order numbers in one drop-down ?  in magento

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
?>
<select >
 <option value="">None</option>
  <?php foreach($orders as $order) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>"><?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: when i select the drop down order how can i show status ...?

Comment: you want to show order status on selection of dropdown?

Comment: yes ...but how ?

Comment: add new question and add your html too and point out where you want display that... give me link of that..